# Multiple entries appearing in Image Gallery's list of applications to handle share/send intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two intent filters associated with different activities in my manifest:

1)

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/my_label" >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
```

2)

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/my_label" >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
```

However, when I select an album from ImageGallery and click on the share/send icon I get two entries appearing in the list of apps which can handle this action.

If I remove the SEND_MULTIPLE from the second intent filter then all is well.

Am I specifying the intent filter incorrectly? Thanks in advance. Peter.